# Работа с WinSock в C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, winsock, c++

Начал изучать WinSock, в связи с этим возникло множество вопросов.
**Первый**:
Есть код

```
#include <winsock2.h>

__fastcall TForm3::TForm3(TComponent* Owner) 
    : TForm(Owner)  
{  
    WSADATA wsd;  
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsd)!=0)  
    {  
        Memo1->Lines->Add("Ошибка старта сокета");  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        Memo1->Lines->Add("Библиотека Работает");  
        SOCKET S;  
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr;  
        S=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

        servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_port=htons(28960); //порт сервера
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("IPшник.до.серва.ка");

        char *buf = "\xff\xff\xff\xff getstatus";
        S=send(S,buf,sizeof(buf),0); // делал и просто send(S,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
    }
}
```

Я всё прописал там - айпишники, порты, запускаю программу, и ничего не происходит - почему? 
Точнее в мемо пишет "Библиотека Работает" и всё. интернет монитор не регистрирует новых открывшихся портов, сниффер не регистрирует никакой активности (отправки пакета на сервер). 
Как его "активировать" что ли? Для этого надо еще один сокет создавать - т.н. "исходящий"?

**Второй**: как мне в будущем сделать, что бы при нажатии определенной кнопки отправлялась определенная инфа серверу?

Comment: Всё, со всем разобрался, можно вопрос закрыть:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для UDP надо использовать sendto(), а не send().

Comment: А что бы принять инфу с сервера, нужно еще один сокет открывать и биндить порт на своём компе? Да и вообще - по идее же при создании сокета моя программа у себя должна открыть ip и порт, с которого отправлять будет?

Comment: разобрался:)